# Как объединить столбцы, зная лишь количество в PHPExcell?

Tags: php, excel

Нужно объединить столбцы, количество которых, например, 10 (может меняться динамически).

В доках нашел пример:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('A1:C1');
```

Но мне неизвестна буква последнего столбца.

Как можно объединить столбцы, зная лишь их количество?

Comment: Рассчитайте букву конечного столбца, зная начальный.

Comment: $i = 10;
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('A1:' . $i . '1');

Comment: такой вариант, почему-то, не работает

Comment: Естественно, `$i` это число. Вы же понимаете разницу между числом и буквой?

Comment: не хотелось бы забивать руками массив с английскм алфавитом и потом вычислять номер литеры. Думаю, есть более лаконичный метод...

Comment: Алфавит генерируется через `range('A', 'Z')`